# Will php's json_encode() always use double quotes as string delimiter?

Tags: php, json

I have a php associative array containing strings as values and I encode it to JSON and store it in an html-data attribute. That is read by some JS.

So far so good.

Now, I need to use single quotes for the data attribute, otherwise the context switches.

```
<section id="settings" data-settings='{"some":"val"}'>
</section>
```

The question is, can I rely on the `json_encode()` function of php to encode strings always with double quotes? Surprisingly, I can't seem to find information on this. I only find articles from people having issues with quotes in the array values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the [ECMA 404 JSON Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), yes, it will always use double quotes (see figure 5)

Comment: Yes, but single quotes in the strings themselves will cause issues

Comment: _“Now, I need to use single quotes for the data attribute, otherwise the context switches”_ – no, you just need to properly handle the data before you put it into the HTML context. `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, as defined in the JSON spec, the delimiter will always be `"`. However, values may contain `'` characters, which would break your HTML. To keep it simple and not worry about what might or mightn't pose an issue, **HTML-escape** your values!

```
<section data-settings="<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($foo)); ?>"></section>
```

This is guaranteed to work, always, no matter what values you pipe in or how you encode them.

**NOTE** that [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) will by default only encode `"`, not `'`; so you must use `"` as the delimiter in HTML (or change the default escaping behavior).

Comment: Your note saved me a lot of frustration and I almost skimmed over it! I'm going add some formatting to make it a little more prominent.

Answer (score 2):

Double-quotes is just convention - standard in JSON in many languagues. So if you want to store JSON in HTML attribute with double-quotes. You can encode that
**In PHP**

```
$encoded_json = base64_encode(json_encode($var));
```

**In HTML**

```
<section id="settings" data-settings='<?=$encoded_json?>'>
```

**In JS**

```
var variable = JSON.parse(atob(encoded_json));
```